# Converting from different arrays to standard form

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, bitmap

I would prefer a small sample code that i could remake into a larger scale of this question(s), or a link to a specific question/tutorial regarding these question(s).

What i have done is i've stored an array of bitmaps to a ArrayList (because i couldn't store it to Bitmap[]), now what i want to do is AL and turn it into a Bitmap[] or take the content from it and add it straight to my variable Bitmap a1, a2, a3; //and so forth

I also wish to do this, but with a String[], i have done the same as the above exept stored it in a String[] now, i wish to store it to the variables String b1, b2, b3; //and so forth

I also wish to do this with a Double[] you know the drill..
I've looked around for something like this, but the only one i came close to finding something relevant was with the String array, however the code/tutorial wasn't made for my problem, i tried to figure out a way of making it possible, but to no success..

```
public class LVFinal extends Activity{


Bitmap a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12, a13, a14, a15, a16, a17, a18, a19, a20, a21, a22, a23, a24, a25, a26, a27, a28, a29, a30, a31, a32, a33, a34, a35, a36, a37, a38, a39, a40, a41, a42, a43, a44, a45, a46, a47, a48, a49, a50, a51, a52, a53, a54, a55, a56, a57, a58, a59, a60, a61, a62, a63, a64, a65, a66, a67, a68, a69, a70, a71, a72, a73, a74, a75, a76, a77, a78, a79, a80, a81, a82, a83, a84, a85, a86, a87, a88, a89, a90, a91, a92, a93, a94, a95, a96, a97, a98, a99, a100;
CharSequence b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10, b11, b12, b13, b14, b15, b16, b17, b18, b19, b20, b21, b22, b23, b24, b25, b26, b27, b28, b29, b30, b31, b32, b33, b34, b35, b36, b37, b38, b39, b40, b41, b42, b43, b44, b45, b46, b47, b48, b49, b50, b51, b52, b53, b54, b55, b56, b57, b58, b59, b60, b61, b62, b63, b64, b65, b66, b67, b68, b69, b70, b71, b72, b73, b74, b75, b76, b77, b78, b79, b80, b81, b82, b83, b84, b85, b86, b87, b88, b89, b90, b91, b92, b93, b94, b95, b96, b97, b98, b99, b100;
Double c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10, c11, c12, c13, c14, c15, c16, c17, c18, c19, c20, c21, c22, c23, c24, c25, c26, c27, c28, c29, c30, c31, c32, c33, c34, c35, c36, c37, c38, c39, c40, c41, c42, c43, c44, c45, c46, c47, c48, c49, c50, c51, c52, c53, c54, c55, c56, c57, c58, c59, c60, c61, c62, c63, c64, c65, c66, c67, c68, c69, c70, c71, c72, c73, c74, c75, c76, c77, c78, c79, c80, c81, c82, c83, c84, c85, c86, c87, c88, c89, c90, c91, c92, c93, c94, c95, c96, c97, c98, c99, c100;
ArrayList<Bitmap> aMaster;
Bitmap[] bitmapArray;
String[] sMaster;
Double[] dMaster;

private List<LVSecond> myList = new ArrayList<LVSecond>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    aMaster = ConnectMySQL.getRankingPic();
    sMaster = ConnectMySQL.getName();
    dMaster = ConnectMySQL.getRank();
    charSequenceRet(); //same as below pretty much
    bitmapReturn(); //this will return a1, a2, a3 and so on, but in normal bitmap(s) so i can use it in my code for custom listview
    doubleReturn(); // same as above pretty much
```

this is from ConnectMySQL class

```
public static String[] getName(){
    connection();
    try {
        Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(host, username, password);
        PreparedStatement statement = connect.prepareStatement("SELECT users.displayname, users.gender FROM users, picture WHERE users.id=picture.user_id ORDER BY picture.finalsum DESC LIMIT 100");
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        rs.first(); 
        while (!rs.isAfterLast()){ 
            list.add(rs.getString("displayname"));
            rs.next(); 
        }

        result = new String[list.size()];
        result = list.toArray(result); 
        statement.close();
        connect.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /*for(int i =0; i<result.length; i++){
          System.out.println(result[i]);
    }*/
    return result;
}

public static void InsertImage(String user_id, String gender, Byte image, String filePath) {
    connection();
    try {
        Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(host, username, password);
        PreparedStatement statement = connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO picture (user_id, gender, image) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
        statement.setString(2, user_id);
        statement.setString(3, gender);                     
        statement.setByte(8, image);
        statement.executeUpdate();
        statement.close();
        connect.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static Double[] getRank(){
    connection();
    try {
        Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(host, username, password);
        PreparedStatement statement = connect.prepareStatement("SELECT picture.finalsum FROM users, picture WHERE users.id=picture.user_id ORDER BY picture.finalsum DESC LIMIT 100");
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
        ArrayList<Double> intList = new ArrayList<Double>();
        rs.first(); 
        while (!rs.isAfterLast()){ 
            intList.add(rs.getDouble("finalsum"));
            rs.next(); 
        }   

        rank = new Double[intList.size()];
        rank = intList.toArray(rank); 
        statement.close();
        connect.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /*for(int i =0; i<result.length; i++){
          System.out.println(result[i]);
    }*/
    return rank;
}


public static ArrayList<Bitmap> getRankingPic(){
    connection();
    ArrayList<Bitmap> bmpList = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    Bitmap bmp;
    byte[] byteArray;
    try {
        Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(host, username, password);
        PreparedStatement statement = connect.prepareStatement("SELECT picture.image FROM users, picture WHERE users.id=picture.user_id ORDER BY picture.finalsum DESC LIMIT 100");
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
        rs.first(); 
        while (!rs.isAfterLast()){ 
            byteArray = null;
            bmp = null;
            while (byteArray == null){
            byteArray = rs.getBytes("image");
            }
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
            byteArray, 0,
            byteArray.length);
            bmpList.add(bmp);
            rs.next(); 
        }   
        statement.close();
        connect.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /*for(int i =0; i<result.length; i++){
          System.out.println(result[i]);
    }*/
    return bmpList;
}
```

edit: questions:
1. How do i turn String[] into normal string(s)? String[] contains 100 different strings, now i wish to have those strings implanted in b1, b2, b3 etc

1. I have something called ArrayList this is basically the same as a bitmap array, however it's not exactly the same, so i want to know how do i convert this into the variables a1, a2, a3 (these are bitmap variables) if i can't do it like this how do i convert it into Bitmap[] then do it?
2. How do i turn Double[] into normal doubles? stored as c1, c2, c3 etc

OBS: i have written to normal String, i wish to convert it into CharSequence, i'll fix it up shortly!

Comment: Please post some code. It's really unclear what you have and what you want.

Comment: you couldn't convert to a string array with .toArray() and work from there?

Comment: @KarolS i've edited it, should be more clear, if not please ask.

Comment: could you edit with a question (...?) It will force the crux of your problem to come to light. I'm a bit in the open as to what you want. thx.

Comment: ok I see what you want. sorry

Comment: if all you want is a Bitmap[], you need a sum of the total size so iterate down the list and collect the size and then create a function with variables storing your position that adds to the list. I have no idea what AL is and there may be a better way to do this.

Comment: ahh ok i updated the question either way, incase others have trouble @AndrewScottEvans

Comment: you would need a loop for all of this. .length will give you the length of an array. multidimensional arrays are arrays of arrays and there is not concatenation like in python. you need to iterate down all arrays or arrays in arrays and place them in variables. you could store the variables in a separate list and match them to their coutnerparts. I reccomend a normal for loop. as for your string, use a Stringbuilder or StringBuffer in the loop, it has an .add() method. Strings are immutable but have .concat()

Comment: Thanks, it'll help quite a bit, however i misspoke i have written to normal String, i wish to convert it into CharSequence

Comment: `Bitmap a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12, a13, a14, a15, a16, a17, a18, a19, a20, a21, a22, a23, a24, a25, a26, a27, a28, a29, a30, a31, a32, a33, a34, a35, a36, a37, a38, a39, a40, a41, a42, a43, a44, a45, a46, a47, a48, a49, a50, a51, a52, a53, a54, a55, a56, a57, a58, a59, a60, a61, a62, a63, a64, a65, a66, a67, a68, a69, a70, a71, a72, a73, a74, a75, a76, a77, a78, a79, a80, a81, a82, a83, a84, a85, a86, a87, a88, a89, a90, a91, a92, a93, a94, a95, a96, a97, a98, a99, a100;` It is insane to declare so many variables. Use an array instead. You are fired ;-).

Comment: @greenapps you think i don't know that? i tried with an array, but i couldn't make it work...

Comment: Why didn't you come here to make the array implementation working? Would be more logical.

Comment: @greenapps yeah... think i'm going to make another question about it :s seems to be a LOT better of a solution :s but still got some useful info about this question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you want, but it sounds like you basically want to convert from an ArrayList to an array. You could do that with the toArray method of ArrayList.

For Example:

```
bitmapArray = new Bitmap[aMaster.size()];
bitmapArray = aMaster.toArray(bitmapArray);
```

UPDATED ANSWER:

**How do you turn String[] into normal strings?**

First of all, CharSequence is an interface in Java, not a class. You can't create a CharSequence object. A string is-a CharSequence. Check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html if you would like to read more into it.

Now, I don't see a benefit in creating all of those variables for each element in the array. I'd say it's a bad practice to do so. Why not just access an element with sMaster[x]?

**How do I turn Double[] into normal doubles?**

To cast from a Double to a double:

```
// assume before is a variable with some Double value
double after = (double) before;
```

To turn a Double[] into a double[]:

```
double[] doubleArray = new double[dMaster.length];
for(int k = 0; k < doubleArray.length; k++(
{
    doubleArray[k] = (double) dMaster[k];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but unlike normal question on stack, i asked a couple more.. i know this is why your not suppose to do that, but they have so much in common. This will help greatly tho, thanks.